# What is wrong in this case since returning custom set of type from postgres function

Tags: postgresql

My Table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE dev.clbk_logs
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    clbk_typ character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    clbk_json json,
    cre_dte timestamp without time zone,
    ld_id bigint,
    ld_num character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    mod_dte timestamp without time zone,
    CONSTRAINT clbk_logs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
```

And my stored procedure as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dev.get_ranged_loads(p_callback_types TEXT[],p_loads TEXT[], p_days_ago_1 INT, p_days_ago_2 INT) 
RETURNS table(
    clbk_json json,
    ld_id character varying,
    ld_num character varying,
    days_ago int)

AS $BODY$ 
BEGIN
    return query    
    
    SELECT a.clbk_json,a.ld_id,a.ld_num,(current_date - a.cre_dte::date) as _days_ago 
    FROM dev.clbk_logs a 
    WHERE exists (
    SELECT * from json_array_elements_text(a.clbk_json -> 'ReferenceNumbers') as x(item) 
    WHERE x.item = any(p_loads) 
    AND a.clbk_typ = any(p_callback_types)
    AND ((current_date - a.cre_dte::date)=p_days_ago_1 OR (current_date - a.cre_dte::date)<p_days_ago_2) 
) order by  a.cre_dte desc;
       
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Currently this is giving me an error

ERROR:  cannot change return type of existing function
DETAIL:  Row type defined by OUT parameters is different.
HINT:  Use DROP FUNCTION dev.get_ranged_loads(text[],text[],integer,integer) first.
SQL state: 42P13

What is getting wrong in above code

I am expecting the result set as

```
|---------|---------|------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|------------|
| id      |clbk_typ |clbk_json   |cre_dte         |          ld_id |ld_num          |mod_dte         |days_ago    |
|---------|---------|------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|------------|
| 1172    |ADD      | {}         |  0             |  12            |                |                |           | 
| 1172    |UPDATE   | {}         |  40            |  45            |                |                |           |
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. You can't change the return type. Run:

```
DROP FUNCTION dev.get_ranged_loads(TEXT[],TEXT[],INT,INT);
```

and then you'll be able to run `CREATE OR REPLACE` as usual.

Comment: Thanks, this was quite simple to notice. but somehow I missed  the error since getting loaded with different errors. So, I directly jumped on here. thanks you. now it resolved my error.

Comment: @DnyaneshwarJadhav, you should accept the answer if it solved your problem. This is the reason people put effort in answering questions and solving problems on SO

Comment: Actually I had given my votes. but seems like I do have some restrictions to make those votes visible, I am new on this platform. only 5 days older profile. Hope you know all the restrictions here. Thanks